# What's happening here in this for loop

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I was trying something else but suddenly stuck with this infinite loop .
Please suggest an answer with explanation that what's going on here in the below for loop

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int x=0;
 int i;
 int array[5];
 for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
 {
  array[i]=x;
  printf("#%d value set in index %d\n",x,i);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

When I remove `=` sign in the condition of `for` loop It works fine.

But when I put this it goes to infinite loop , Why?
Accessing extra element (more than its limit) in array is undefined behaviour or what ?
Any help will appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

~

Comment: Seeking clarity on an undefined behavior due to intentional error is waste of time...your pc might as well fly to mars ..

Comment: Yes, accessing extra element (more than its limit) in array is 'undefined behaviour'. It may show infinity loop in yours, in another compiler/pc/system it may behave different way. Better not waste time after undefined behaviour and check your code and fix the problem following the standard (in this case making 'i < 5' in the condition of 'for' loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid causing errors like this as easily, here's two good rules for writing `for` loops over actual (local) arrays:

1. Iteration starts at index 0, since C's arrays are 0-based.
2. Use `<`, always. Never `<=`.
3. Don't repeat the size, let the compiler compute it using `sizeof array / sizeof *array`. Note the asterisk in the second term.

So, this loop should have been written:

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof array / sizeof *array; i++)
```

and then you would have been safe.

Note that this only works for "real" arrays that have a size visible to `sizeof`, if you've let the array "collapse" into a pointer it won't work.

Also note that `sizeof` is not a function, so no `()`s are necessary around its argument in cases like these.

Answer (score 5):

You're writing 6 ints to an array with space for 5.  The 6th write is outside the bounds of the array so its effect is unpredictable.  In your case, its writing to the next `sizeof(int)` bytes of stack.  This is the memory used for `i`, the loop counter, which gets reset to 0.

As you say in your question, the fix for this is to replace the `<=` exit condition of your for loop with `<`.

Comment: But how it's writing to "i" can you please tell me ...

Comment: Yeah I know it exceeding the array's limit but wanted to know about the modification of i variabel

Comment: @Omkant I've updated my post to (try to) cover this

Comment: It means the address of i is same as array[5] ?

Answer (score 2):

Undefined behavior happens when `i==5`. `array` has valid indexes `0..4` - arrays in C are 0-based.

If you replace `<=` with `<`, you iterate through valid indexes.

> Accessing extra element (more than its limit) in array is undefined behaviour or what ?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Why you're going into an infinite loop, in this specific case, is actually pretty easy to understand, take a look at the addresses on your stack:

```
int main( ) 
{
    int x = 0;
    int i;
    int array[5];
    printf("&x = %#x, &i = %#x, array = %#x, array+4 = %#x\n", &x, &i, array, array+4);
```

The result of this `printf()` will show you the addresses of your variables and the start and end of the array:

```
&x = 0xbfac9cec, &i = 0xbfac9ce8, array = 0xbfac9cd4, array+4 = 0xbfac9ce4
```

So in order, your stack looks like:

```
 var        address
***********************
array[0]    0xbfac9cd4
array[1]    0xbfac9cd8
array[2]    0xbfac9cdc
array[3]    0xbfac9ce0
array[4]    0xbfac9ce4
  i         0xbfac9ce8
  x         0xbfac9cec
```

Now your loop is writing 0-5 (6 elements), there are only 5 elements in your array so writing to the 6th actually overwrites the next thing on the stack which is `i` in this case. 
That makes this line:

```
array[i]=x;
```

The same as writing this:

```
i = x;
```

That will store 0 (in your case) to i, and restart the loop, so you're going to see it loop forever and print "0 stored to index 0", then "index 1", 2, 3, 4 then restart again when you set `i=x;`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to store 6 int values in an array of size 5, which is illegal.

So when you try to write at the 6th position of the array, you are writing into the variable `i` with the value of `x` (which is 0).
Now in your next iteration since `i` is 0, it is less than the condition specified in the `for` loop. This causes your loop to run all over again and again!

Comment: I got it btw .. but anyway explained good so +1

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should go from 0 to 4 as your array has 5 elements

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int x=0;
 int i;
 int array[5];
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
  array[i]=x;
  printf("#%d value set in index %d\n",x,i);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read question completely that's not my problem .. I know this which you have given but the question is why is it going to infinite loop

Comment: Sorry.Obviously you are overflowing your array which have unexpected behavior like overwriting your i variable (who knows). What does your printf issues on the console after i==4?

Comment: it's printing 5 lines and repeating it in a loop

Comment: Try to output printf("0x%x vs 0x%x \n", array + 6, &i) and compare adresses if you want to check for yourself.

Comment: @user1654209 - Just FYI, `%#x` will save a step when displaying a hex address, it prints the `0x` for you.