# Why is there an infinite loop in my program?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, infinite-loop

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int array[5];

    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    array[i] = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the above code stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: stack scribble...But congratulations! You wrote a 5 line program that does nothing and yet goes for a long time!

Comment: Downvoters - the down vote is used when the questions is written badly or doesn't follow the site's rules, not for trivial questions!

Comment: possible duplicate of this question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010004/whats-happening-here-in-this-for-loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what happenning in the given code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int array[5];

    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%p %p \n",&i,&array[i]);
        printf("the value of i is %d \n",i);
        sleep(1);
        array[i] = 0;
        printf("i may be modified here lets see what i is %d \n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

in my stack memory I got the address locations as

`i` is stored at location 0xbfd1048c address

and `array` is stored at location  0xbfd10478 address

As you are incrementing `i` value for each loop at one point of time the address of `array[i]` is equivalent to address of `i` (its just pointer dereferencing)

So what you are storing at `array[i]` is nothing but the `i`'s instance address so you are over writing the `i`'s instance value to 0 as you have mentioned `array[i] = 0` which is equivalent to `i=0` so the condition `i<=20` always succeeds.

Now the BIG question why does the memory allocated in such a way.

It is decided at run time and on the availability of the resources to the kernel.

So that's why we have to dwell with in the limits of the array.

Comment: The sample code & logging of addresses is a nice approach to an answer.  One small point - the offset between items on the stack was decided at compile-time, not at run-time.

Comment: The layout of the stack-frame (both i and array are on the stack) is decided by the compiler

Answer (score 21):

You declare an array with 5 elements but write 21 elements to it.  Writing past the end of an array results in undefined behaviour.  In you case, you're writing to the loop counter `i`, resetting it to 0, probably when you assign `array[5]`.

If you want to fix your program, change the loop to write to the correct number of elements

```
int num_elems = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
for (i = 0; i < num_elems ; i++)
```

Answer (score 8):

You are invoking undefined behaviour by overwriting beyond the memory you are allowed. So anything can happen.

Most likely, it's overwriting the loop counter.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you try to access an element outside the bounds of the array, which is only 5 big - but in a loop that is 21 big.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int array[5];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    array[i] = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any infinite loop condition, but you're setting up to 20 values on an array with 5 "slots"???