# Reason Why this Happens in c

Tags: c, gcc

i am using gcc and i have written this code and intentionally loop is written wrong

```
int main() {
  int a[3][3];
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  int num=0;
  for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
      a[i][j]=0;
    }
  }
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
      printf("%d",a[i][j]);
  return 0;
}
```

when I do `a[i][j]=0;` or `a[i][j]=1;` it goes to infinite loop but when I enter other than 0 or 1 it executes correctly.

Can anybody tell me why this happens?

Comment: you are accessing 4 element and you specifed 3 in the matrix. `j < 3` and `i<3` will correct your issue

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14020402/4389800