# why does this program go into an infinite loop?

Tags: c

```
main()
{
int i;
int a[5];
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    a[i] = 0;
printf("Hello, how are you? ");
}
```

why is the program not coming out of the loop?

Comment: Arrays in C use zero-based indices. Valid indices for your array are 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there an infinite loop in my program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020402/why-is-there-an-infinite-loop-in-my-program)

Comment: So, what was your answer in the interview, and did you get the job? ;)

Comment: I would also point out that there is ABSOLUTELY no guarantee that this will end in an infinite loop. It may do, but i could be held in a register for the duration of the entire execution. Or, if it's On a 64-bit system, since stack is always aligned to 8 bytes, 5 * 4 = 20 gets rounded to 24 bytes and thus the extra 0 gets written to a "unused" location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's happening here in this for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010004/whats-happening-here-in-this-for-loop)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C arrays are zero-based so you should use indexes [0..4] rather than [1..5].

Writing to `a[5]` writes beyond the bounds of your array.  This has undefined results; in your case, this happens to be the address of your loop counter `i` which is reset to 0.

You can fix this by using

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

or, better,

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
```

as your loop.

Comment: Actually, he is writing 5 elements - but starting from 1 instead of zero. (This pedantic note does not change the correct main reasoning of this answer) (+1)

Comment: To add to your answer, arrays in C and zero-based not 1-based: i.e. the valid index values for a[5] are 0 through 4, not 1 through 5.

Comment: +1 for overwriting the loop counter explanation. Where is that documented?

Comment: @axeoth It's not, it's UB. That's just the most likely explanation.

Comment: @amit, Thanks, I'd missed that the loop was starting from array index 1.  I've updated my answer accordingly now

Comment: @ChrisW Thanks, I've updated my answer as per your suggestion

Comment: @sepp2k: Thanks. But... what the "UB" means?

Comment: @axeoth UB means Undefined Behaviour.  Its what I meant by saying that writing beyond the end of the array had undefined results.  Different compilers could behave differently here.

Comment: @axeoth It's undefined behavior - like simonc said in his answer.

Comment: @simonc: OK, OK... I know what undefined behavior is, I just did not linked the UB with... the undefined behavior.

Comment: @simonc And so could the same compiler at different optimization levels or with a slightly changed program.

Comment: .. or even better `int a[5] = {0};` if you're using a remotely modern C compiler (but +1 on a great explanation of 0-based indexing and UB).

Answer (score 5):

You're accessing the array out of bounds (the legal indices for an array of size 5 are indices 0 to 4, not 1 to 5). As far as the standard is concerned, this means your program invokes undefined behavior and can behave any way it pleases.

In terms of the actual implementation, what's actually happening is probably that your last array access (i.e. `a[5] = 0;`) write over variable that comes after `a` in memory, which happens to be `i` on your system. So `i` is reset to 0 and the loop continues forever.

Comment: +1 for the best solution among the all. All other are are incomplete answers

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int a[5];
int i;
printf("Memory location of i = %p\n",&i);
printf("Memory location of a[5] = %p\n",&a[5]);
for (i = 1; i <=5; i++)
{
    a[i] = 0;
    sleep (2);
   printf("Value of i=%d\n",i);
}
printf("Hello, how are you? \n");
}
```

---

See the o/p it is interesting .. [ will understood why value of i became 0(Zero)]

```
mnds@mind-AcerPower-Series:/tmp$ ./a.out 
Memory location of i = 3218951772
Memory location of a[5] = 3218951772
Value of i=1
Value of i=2
Value of i=3
Value of i=4
Value of i=0
```

Comment: +1 Even though this has already been stated twice in different answers, code to back it up is always a good thing.

Comment: except that the OP defined variable i *before* defining the array. Maybe the compiler optimized and placed i after. Anyway, it should be interesting to have a look at it.

Comment: @Arun: You should use %p for printing the address, not %u.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing `a[5]`, that's outside the boundary.

Your loop should be:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass the size of the integer array, array size is 5 so maximum `a[4]` is accessible.
Try this:

```
main()
{
    int i;
    int a[5];
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        a[i] = 0;
    printf("Hello, how are you? ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it invokes undefined behavior, so anything can happen (infinite loops included).

When your array has 5 elements, the indices of these elements range from 0 to 4. Accessing `a[5]` is an invalid operation.

Arrays in C are zero-indexed, so in order your program to work correctly, you should have written

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```